# How does assigning variables to functions work in this python program?

Tags: python, function

Here is the full python program on pastebin
https://pastebin.com/0syTHsJX

,I dont understand how the variable assigned to the function mutable_link() works. if i replace s with mutable_link

```
for element in reversed(source):
        mutable_link()('push_first', element)
    return mutable_link()
```

Here is the version that works though.

```
        s = mutable_link()
        for element in reversed(source):
            s('push_first', element)
        return s
```

How does assigning the function to variables work and why do i get error when i use just mutable_link() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your code and found that.

1. In the first case  `mutable_link()` call again and again and then set the `contents` value to `'empty'`.
2. But in the second case `mutable_link()` call only once and does not change the `contents` again and again.

Comment: I think you might be right.. Thanks!